# Ext2 utility "e2cp" alternative for OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystems, ext2, diskimage

In my linux machines, I use the command line utility e2cp to copy files from and to ext2 disk images. Unfortunately, OS X does not provide any ext2fs utility out of the box.
Is there a version of e2cp that is compatible to OS X, or a similar alternative? Notice that I don't need to mount or do anything advanced, I just have to copy files.

Comment: duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208047/7057 has an answer

Comment: @glennjackman unfortunately, that is not really what I am looking for, as I explained in the comments.